# PostgreSQL oximoron

Tags: postgresql

[image]

Hi all,

Can any understand what's going on here?

The case is:

There are 2 tables, called "matricula" and "pagament" with a 1:1 relationship cardinality.

Table matricula primary key composed by 3 fields "edicio","curs" and "estudiant".

Table pagament primary key, the same as above. Furthermore, it references matricula.

As shown, trying to insert a row in pagament table is rejected because it does not exists a row in table matricula. However, asking for this row returns one result.

What am I missing?

Thanks you all

Carles

Comment: thank you very much horse, the solution has been found.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the order of the fields in both tables is not the same, and, moreover, the restriction of the foreign key in table pagament, said that

```
foreign key (estudiant,curs,edicio) references matricula
```

without specifying the matricula fields.

It's been solved by setting this restriction as

```
foreign key (estudiant,curs,edicio) references matricula(estudiant,curs,edicio)
```